# C++17 refuses to compile example if constexpr giving expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’

Tags: g++, c++17

I am trying out this text-book example of using if constexpr and I am getting error `expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’` when compiling.

I am compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp` so the version should support it. Visual Studio Code understands this and hints that this expression will be compiled to number `120` (correct).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <int N>
constexpr int fun() {
    if constexpr (N <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return N * fun<N - 1>();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout << fun<5>() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code should compile error-free

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? You need at least gcc-7 for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a more recent version of GCC. Version 7 and up support this. See:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp17

(Search for "constexpr if".)

So upgrade your GCC version. If you're on Ubuntu, you can add the Toolchain PPA to install the latest available GCC version:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

Comment: Thank you. I had my doubts, but I was able to compile with C++17 flag and so I crossed out compiler version from the list. Indeed, running with `g++-7` makes it work.